# Getting streaming data from gun

Tags: database, gun

`on()` is supposed to stream data from a path or key [<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/JS-API#on-gungetkeyoncallback-options).  But when I `put` data on my path, I'm not seeing the updated stream.

```
var myData = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun')
             .get('example/demo/set');
myData.on();
myData.put({hello:'world'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on()` is an **asynchronous** function, so you need to update your code to look like this:

```
var myData = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun')
             .get('example/demo/set');
myData.on(function(data){
    console.log("update:", data);
});
myData.put({hello:'world'});
```

Hope that helps!

---

If you are new to programming, "anonymous functions" (often times called a callback) in the above code can be somewhat confusing. The above code can also be rewritten to this, which has the exact same behavior:

```
var myData = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun')
             .get('example/demo/set');

var cb = function(data){
    console.log("update:", data);
};

myData.on(cb);

myData.put({hello:'world'});
```

For debugging purposes, there is also a `.val()` convenience function that will automatically log data for you:

```
var myData = Gun('https://gunjs.herokuapp.com/gun')
             .get('example/demo/set');
myData.on().val()
myData.put({hello:'world'});
```

However it is intended for *one off* purposes, not for streaming. Just as a note, you can pass `.val(function(data){})` a callback which will override the default convenience logger.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: since Gun v0.391 using `val()` also requires a callback. The automatic logging is no longer provided.